# Docker date root moved but old containers and images not found

Tags: docker

By default the docker's images and containers are all saved in the folder `/var/lib/docker`

but that using system's space, and is limited(may be 50G), I want to move the content from there to `/home/docker`(the home folder has 1000G space)

and set that as my new data root by update `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{"data-root":"/home/docker"}
```

But when I restart docker using `systemctl restart docker`
running `docker ps -a` all container disappeared.All the images were disappeared too.

when I remove the data-root setting in `daemon.json` and move things back from `/home/docker` to `/var/lib/docker`,everything comes back(I could see all the container using `docker ps -a`).

Anyone knows how to do this?

I just figure out a way using sym link to solve this:

1. `mv /var/lib/docker/* /home/docker`
2. `ln -s /home/docker /var/lib/docker`

But I still want to find a way without using sym link. Why the hard move way not working? Is there any setting file need to be changed?